# What is difference between Java "int" vs Kotlin "Int" and Java "Integer" vs Kotlin "Int"?

Tags: java, kotlin

In Java, int is a primitive data type representing a 32-bit signed integer. It has a range of -2^31 to 2^31- 1.

In Kotlin, Int is a reference type representing a 32-bit signed integer, similar to Java's Integer wrapper class. Then what is the difference and how memory allocated?

1. Java int:
   int a = 5;
2. Kotlin Int:
   val a: Int = 5
3. Java Integer (for reference):
   Integer a = 5;

How memory allocation happen for storing value ?

Comment: Have you read https://kotlinlang.org/docs/numbers.html#numbers-representation-on-the-jvm ?